# How can I return a number between commas?

Tags: python, list, search

I have a text file which contains a list of prime numbers, however, they are between two commas at every line as in the following:

```
1, 2, 2
2, 3, 1
3, 5, 2
4, 7, 2
...
```

How can I make a code that returns the nth prime or, equivalently, the prime number between two commas at the nth line?

Comment: `.split()` and `.strip()` are your friends.

Comment: You need to split the text into parts. Have you searched for this problem? What were the results?

Comment: You may also want to look at using the [comma separated value (csv) support in Python](https://realpython.com/python-csv/)  to read in the text file and build up a list of primes that way.  If you give it a shot, we can provide more feedback.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.

Comment: See [How much research?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
def n_prime(n):
  with open('file.txt','r') as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
      if i == n:
        return line.split(',')[1].strip()

print(n_prime(0)) # 2
print(n_prime(1)) # 3
print(n_prime(2)) # 5
print(n_prime(3)) # 7
```

Input: file.txt

```
1, 2, 2
2, 3, 1
3, 5, 2
4, 7, 2
```

Comment: Your code is for every line of the list, how could I do it for a specific line?

Comment: @OrdpT I've edited my answer. You can just do `prime_list[n]` to get the `nth` prime number from the file.

Comment: It's a interesting way, but i don't believe it's efficient, since I'm working with a list of 100,000 primes

Comment: @OrdpT To read a line in a file you can only do it after reading all the lines that come before it. There is no other way other than to count each line until you reach the line you want to process. All libraries do that

Comment: @OrdpT I've edited my solution. Is this better?

Comment: @OrdpT upvote and mark it as answer if it helped you. Thanks

Comment: It truly helped! Thank you!